# Change input value [not reflected inside HTML]

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change input value of a checkbox when it is checked/unchecked. It seems the value is changed (I debugged it via alert()) but is not reflected in the html. That's quite troublesome as I want to pull the value from the html and save it in a database.

```
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#box:checked").live('click', function(e) {
                        $("#box").val('1');                          
                    });

                    $("#box:not(:checked)").live('click', function(e) {
                        $("#box").val('0');                            
                    });    
                 });

    ... 

      <input id="box" type="checkbox" value="">

    ...
```

I've been trying to solve this for hours. I came upon a guy who had the same problem, but the workaround was rather clumsy.

thanks for help

Comment: The HTML *source* cannot be changed... if that is what you mean.

Comment: When you say it's not reflected in the HTML, what exactly do you mean? The markup showed when "View Source" is clicked is not going to change for example. The *DOM* should be updated, and it seems like this is happening if you can show the changed value in an alert box.

Comment: Well, what do you suggest then, if I have a checkbox which have a value that I want to change when clicked?

Comment: @David: The value changes and is sent to the server, but the change is not reflected in the HTML (which is normal). Besides, only the  value of selected checkboxes is sent to the server (if you use a normal POST request).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) for it to be reflected in the HTML.

```
$("#box").attr("checked", "checked");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xeon06/BwGeX/

Comment: Nope, not working. At least not for me. The HTML value remains unchanged.

Comment: Well what do you mean by HTML value? The source code of the file will never be changed, but if you inspect the DOM, using a browser like Chrome, you'll see it will have changed.

Answer (score 1):

`<input id="box" type="checkbox" value="">` - the "value" represents the load time html that the browser renders.

Runtime value of the Form elements are not updated in DOM inspectors

A checkbox's "Checked" value is not related to the "Value" attribute, though it can be manipulated to reflect a different value.

You can obtain the checkbox value as `$("#box").is(':checked')`, this returns true/false

Answer (score 1):

I had to use

```
$("#box").attr('value', '1');
```

in a recent project. For some reason, `.val('1')` wasn't working.